# Can the word "desk" be used as a verb?

Tags: verbs, nouns, verbing

I saw the word *desk* used, according to my thinking, as a verb in a sentence, and I was wondering if this usage is correct or if it was an error from the authors.

You can find the sentence here, at the end of the news section : [ECML PKDD](http://ecmlpkdd2019.org/)

> 5 June 2019
>   Today, we published the list of accepted papers. Out of more than 700 submissions we accepted 102 papers in the research track and 28 papers in the applied data science track. **We desk** rejected several papers for (self-)plagiarism and violation of the double submission policy (together with IJCAI and NeurIPS).

Comment: It looks more like an adverb in the given example but I'm not entirely sure what its meaning is supposed to be in context.

Comment: The candidate verb is the open compound _desk reject_ rather than _desk_. Compare << We colour-coded the trails. >> Novel compound verbs (using the term in the parallel sense to 'compound nouns') are typically hyphenated. // 'Desk' as a verb is not unknown (see Wiktionary), though the compound  'hot-desk' is far more widely used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth King Henry Ⅶ’s will contains: [*But also that the said Chapell **be desked**, and the windowes of our said Chapell be glased, with Stores, Ymagies, Armes, Bagies and Cognoiffaunts, as is by us redily divised, and in picture delivered to the Priour of Saunt Bartilmews besid Smythfield, maistre of the works of our said Chapell…*](https://books.google.com/books?id=uI8PAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=That+the+said+Chapell+be+desked&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnz56Xx6HjAhWVXM0KHRD2B04Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=That%20the%20said%20Chapell%20be%20desked&f=false). Awful speller for a king, wasn’t he? :)

Comment: @tchrist I'd probably have shrunk from pointing out areas for improvement to someone who could accuse opponents of treason.

Comment: Possibly it should be shelved.

Comment: I once heard a seminar on natural language processing where the speaker said "It's well known that in English you can verb any noun." (Not the answer in this case - here "desk: is an adjective.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The expression appears to be from journalistic jargon:

***[Desk Rejected](https://www.google.com/amp/s/avandeursen.com/2012/11/23/desk-rejected/amp/)***

> ... A desk reject means that the program chairs (or editors) reject a paper without consulting the reviewers. This is done for papers that fail to meet the submission requirements, and which hence cannot be accepted. Filtering out desk rejects in advance is common practice for both conferences and journals.

(avandeursen.com)

Comment: This suggests, and the content of the article confirms, that _desk reject_ is (also) being used as an (open form) compound (verb). So the answer is 'It _is_ used as if it was a legitimate lexeme'. As for acceptability: it is in this article a clear usage, well-defined and reasonably constructed. As to how widely understood it is: obviously, at the moment it belongs (if anywhere) solely within the relevant journalistic jargon domain. It would be unreasonable to use it elsewhere without an explanation, as it's not totally transparent (**which/whose** 'desk' does the rejecting? On what grounds?)

Comment: I am **desked** by the audacity of these people.

Comment: This meaning is commonplace in scientific/academic publishing for cases when the editor rejects a manuscript without sending it out to for peer review. The link you provide also discusses this case, as does OP's link. Is it also used in regular journalistic endeavors, e.g. newspapers or magazines?

Answer (score 7):

As noted, your example is probably not *desk* used as a verb.

The *Oxford English Dictionary*
does list *desk* as a verb, but it is marked *obsolete*.  Nevertheless, here is some information about that obsolete verb.

> **1.** transitive. To fit up or furnish with desks.
>     *That the said Chapell be desked.*
>
> **2.** To place in or as in a desk.
>     *A leafe of that small Iliade That in a wall-nut shell was desk't.*
>     *Then are you entertaind, and deskt up by Our Ladies Psalter and the Rosary.*
>     *I..saw many curious relicks desked vp in the side of the wall.*
>
> **3.** to desk it: to work at a desk, do clerical work.

Comment: I don't have a citation offhand, but I've seen it used as v.t. in the sense of "send to a desk", e.g. as an administrative punishment for police or military personnel.

Comment: Dictionary or not, I doubt there are nouns that truly can't be used as verbs in English.

Comment: I think Bart Simpson said: "Every noun can be verbed."

Comment: @GEdgar But are all those verbings equally renounable? :)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's obsolete, lots of firms nowadays 'hot' desk.

Comment: @GEdgar I don’t know who said it (except someone I once knew on a message board), but it’s also been said of English zero-derivation that ***verbing weirds language***.

Answer (score 2):

I will also propose [***hot-desking***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hot-desk), which is an intransitive verb according to *Collins*

> hot-desk
>
> Word forms: hot-desks, hot-desking, hot-desked
>
> intransitive verb
>
> If employees hot-desk, they are not assigned particular desks and work at any desk that is available.
>
> [business]
>
> *Some employees will have to hot-desk until more accommodation can be found*.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hot-desk